# How to apply a non-binary mask on an image in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, mask, smoothing

I'm using OpenCV and I have a gray-scale image that is the result of a smoothing operation on a binary mask:

[image: mask]

I would like to apply this mask to a given RGB image, but using the `copyTo` method with the mask option takes into account all the non-zero pixels of the mask. However, what I'm interested in is to obtain an output image whose RGB pixel values are the input values 'scaled' pixel-wise by the factor given by the gray-scale mask.

I have the feeling that this is possible by using the built-in functions of OpenCV, but so far I couldn't find any way to do what I want.

I would know how to do that from scratch in a brute force fashion, but I'd prefer - if possible - to use built-in functions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How about `cv::addWeighted`?

Comment: How would you use that? `addWeighted` considers a single scalar value, not a matrix of scalars as I need...

Comment: normalize the mask matrix to 0-1 (cv::normalize(maskImg, dstMask, 0., 1., cv::NORM_MINMAX, CV_32F) and then multiply it with the image

Comment: @api55 I wouldn't even bother with normalizing, a simple `convertTo` `CV_32F` with a scale of 1./255 will do.

Comment: @DanMašek true, that would be better, normalize may change the mask values if it does not have the max values (0 or 255)#

Comment: Something like `alpha channel` in `PNG`...

Comment: You're right, `normalize` and `multiply` actually did the trick. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @api55 pointed out, the solution to my problem is:

1. Normalize the mask through the function `cv::normalize`
2. Multiply the normalized mask with the input image through the function `cv::multiply`

In particular, the type of the normalized mask must be set to `CV_32F` (otherwise it won't work). As a consequence, the input image has to be converted as well (e.g., with `convertTo`).

Example code:

```
cv::normalize(mask,mask,0.,1.,cv::NORM_MINMAX,CV_32F);
image.convertTo(image,CV_32F);
cv::multiply(image,mask,image);
image.convertTo(image,CV_8U); // Convert back the input image to the original type
```